# Audio Element "currentTime" not working on Android 6 devices

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

I have this code in my phonegap app.

Basically "this.currentTime" is always being returned as 0 on Android 6 devices and it works on all other devices that I checked.

Anyone knows the reason for this and maybe an alternative solution which works?

```
var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
audioElement.setAttribute("src", track_path);

audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
   alert(this.currentTime);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any console error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the cordova plugin media. Which provide some functions Like 
media.getDuration which returns the duration of an audio file in seconds. If the duration is unknown, it returns a value of -1.

```
media.getDuration();
```

Quick Example

```
// Audio player
//
var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

// Get duration
var counter = 0;
var timerDur = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 100;
    if (counter > 2000) {
        clearInterval(timerDur);
    }
    var dur = my_media.getDuration();
    if (dur > 0) {
        clearInterval(timerDur);
        document.getElementById('audio_duration').innerHTML = (dur) + " sec";
    }
}, 100);
```

here is the reference [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/).

Comment: Sorry, but I need the currentTime of the audio element being played.

Comment: which plugin you are using for that ?

Comment: Not using a plugin, I'm using plain javascript code instead.

Comment: Please view my answers again hopefully it will help you . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bring an old post up, but I ran into the same issue and was able to address this so I wanted to share my solution.

I noticed that for Android Chrome / Webview / Custom Tabs, `currentTime=` function cannot change the time of media elements (video or audio); it always returns back to 0.

The issue was at the media source. The file needs to be served with the HTTP header `Accept-Ranges: 'bytes'` along with the `Content-Length`.

Check within Inspector >> Network >> media file that these headers are present.

Example:

[image: Check for the Accept-Ranges header]

If these are not present, then you will have to modify the server serving the content.